# 64 bit Vs 32 bit Executables

Tags: operating-system, executable

Almost all the executables in market comes in 32 bit and 64 bit versions.

It's a known fact that 32 bit executables would be compatible with 64 bit OS. But not the vice versa.

If this the case, then why do developers have to come with two different executables [32 bit and 64 bit versions] and why not distribute the 32 bit executable alone as the solution [saving the development time of another 64 bit executable].

Also like to know if the 64 bit executable does exist for the support of any performance basis.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The purpose (likely more reasons as well) of 64 bit applications is so that they can utilize larger amounts of memory (RAM) more effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dave is exactly right.  64bit allows you to address more memory than 32 bit versions. The same transition happened when moving from 16bit to 32 bit back in the 90's too.  Here's a good blog post which explains more than you ever wanted to know...

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/32-bit-and-64-bit-explained.htm